# React-onesignal não retorna playerID

Tags: react, typescript, api

Olá, estou tentando retornar o ID único do browser do usuário para salvar esse ID após a permissão de notificação ser concedida pelo usuário no navegador.

Estou usando a lib react-onesignal e quando eu peço o retorno do ID o objeto retorna null ou nem imprime nada no console. Também não tem retorno de status, o ponto é que no browser ta tudo ok, a permissão está concedida porém a função não está retornando esse playerId

```
const Signal = async (): Promise<void> => {
    OneSignal.initialize(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ONE_SIGNAL_APP_ID}`, {
      allowLocalhostAsSecureOrigin: true,
      autoRegister: false,
      notifyButton: {
        prenotify: true,
      },
    })

    const isPush = await OneSignal.isPushNotificationsEnabled()

    if (!isPush) {
      await OneSignal.registerForPushNotifications()
    }

    const permissions = OneSignal.notificationPermission
    const currentState = await OneSignal.getNotificationPermission()
    const playerId = await OneSignal.getPlayerId()
    console.log(playerId)
    console.log('State:', currentState)
    console.log('Permissions:', permissions)
  }
```

Creio que a inicialização do OneSIgnal está correta, só não sei o que falta pra que esteja retornando o ID do user que é a informação que preciso.